# Match multiple lines inside files from pattern ? (Python)

Tags: python

I am trying to verify if inside a file there is the same section as given as pattern inside my script.

I tried to open the file and readlines into a list, but it was not successful when i tried to match the pattern with the file.

Example:
Input file:

1. This is the first line
2. Second line
3. Third line

pattern :

1. Second line
2. Third line

How can i match if the pattern is in my file ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use :

```
with open('file.txt') as my_file:
    print("Second line\nThird line" in my_file.read())
# True
```

If your pattern is longer :

```
pattern = """line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4"""

with open('file.txt') as my_file:
    print(pattern in my_file.read())
# True
```

Comment: Thanks, that is similar to the way I thought about that.
Is there a good way to load a pattern which has , lets say 30 lines into python ? 
Its hard to paste it with the new line separator....

Comment: @HightronicDesign : Answer updated

Comment: Thank you, i will try this now